# Angular Service with Observable implementation

Tags: angular, observable, angular-services, angular-pipe, angular-observable

I've followed many examples to try and get this working but struggling and there seems to be many different ways - so thought best to come here and get an answer.

In simple terms... I have a component that I want to load some data from a JSON file on creation and display it when the data has been loaded.

**appData.model.ts**

```
export interface AppData {
    lastUpdated: string;
}
```

**data.service.ts**

```
  getData(): Observable<AppData> {
    return this.http.get<AppData>('data.json?noCache=' + Math.random());
}
```

**test.component.ts**

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  obsAppData: Observable<AppData>

  constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Test ngOnInit()');
    this.obsAppData = this.dataService.getData();
  }
```

I've then tried to print the value of lastUpdated to the component by using the following code in the html template:

```
{{ obsAppData.lastUpdated | async }}
```

I get no errors in the console but nothing is printing out! Can anyone see anything wrong with the code or any constructive advice on how to debug where the issue is? I think I've picked up Angular quite well, but safe to say I'm struggling with the Observable side of things.

Comment: stackblitz please. Maybe answer is empty?

Comment: where is this file coming from? did  you try to call this HTTP request outside of angular (like postman or direct link) and its work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh i just noticed you are using it wroong. This should work

```
{{ (obsAppData | async).lastUpdated  }}
```

Comment: Ahh bugger. Thanks for that. I've updated my code and it now returns the data but it looks like a few errors are thrown in the console for "Cannot read property 'lastUpdated' of null". Unless I'm doing something else wrong! Is it trying to read lastUpdated before it is populated? If so whats the best way to stop this?

Comment: add the safety like: {{ (obsAppData | async)?.lastUpdated  }}

Comment: Awesome! Great answers. Thanks again. Appears even after a few Angular courses I've still got plenty to learn.

Answer (score -1):

you get data from observabnle return type by subscribing to it.
So in this case what you need to do is

`this.dataService.getData().subscribe(value=> this.obsAppData = value)`

this will get the result of the async opertaion from your service.

Comment: He is using asnyc pipe for that

Comment: Yeah this is where some of my confusion comes from. I have read different articles, some use subscribe, some use async pipe.

Comment: There is no confusion, @Sujay does not know what asyn pipe is

Comment: @Antoniossss I knew about async pipe. I gave him another way of getting result. And it it would be appericiable to post answers rather than commenting about someone whether someone know something or not. I guess you too doesn't know many simple things and that's why this community is there for. So if you know something help others rather than critiscing or you can move on. Peace :)

Answer (score -1):

In your service use:

```
getData() {
    return this.http.get<AppData>('data.json?noCache=' + Math.random())
         .pipe(
            map((response: Response) => return response.json())
         )
}
```

In your component.ts use:

```
export class TestComponent implements OnInit {
  appData: this.dataSericie.appData;
}
```

In your component.html use what you already used:

```
{{ appData.lastUpdated | async }}
```

And I might be mistaking but I don't think you need the Math.random() on the local files.

Comment: The Math.random() is to ensure the json is retrieved from the server, otherwise the browser caches it - which I don't want.

Comment: JSON is the default response type for AG5+